# A question about dominated convergence theorem in a proof

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I have a couple of questions about statements in a proof.
Let

$$\Psi_M(x) = \begin{cases}
x & \text{on } x\in [0,M-1] \\
      0 & \text{on } x\in [M,\infty]\\
      \mathrm{linear } & \text{on } x\in [M-1,M]
\end{cases}$$

Q1) I have a family $\{X_n\}$ and $X$ s.t. $E|X|<\infty$. DCT $\implies E|X| = \text{lim}_M E\Psi_M(|X|)$. May I know what is $\Psi_M(|X|)$ dominated by which is integrable?

Q2) Why is $E(|X_n|;|X_n|>M)\leq E|X_n|-E\Psi_M(|X_n|)$?

$E(|X_n|;|X_n|>M) = E|X_n|- E(|X_n|;|X_n|<M)$ and I'm not sure why $E(|X_n|;|X_n|<M)\geq E\Psi_M(|X_n|)$ because again how can I know $E(|X_n|;|X_n|\in [M-1,M])\geq E[\Psi_M(|X_n|);|X_n|\in [M-1,M]]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, $0\leq \Psi_M(x)\leq x$ for all $x\geq0$.

For Q1, the dominated variable is $|X|$, which is integrable.

For Q2, since $$E\Psi_M(|X_n|)=E[\Psi_M(|X_n|);|X_n|\leq M]\leq E(|X_n|;|X_n|\leq M),$$
we have
$E(|X_n|;|X_n|>M)=E|X_n|-E(|X_n|;|X_n|\leq M)\leq E|X_n|-E\Psi_M(|X_n|)$.

Comment: Thanks. May I know why $\Psi_M(x)\leq x$ in $[M-1,M]$. Is it implicit that $\Psi_M$ decreases from $M-1$ to $0$ in $[M-1,M]$ linearly or something like that?

Comment: @manifolded If you draw a picture, you will see the clearness. In $[M-1,M]$, the picture is a linear segment connecting two points $(M-1,M-1)$ and $(M,0)$, which is decreasing apparently. So for $x\in[M-1,M]$, $\Psi_M(x)\leq M-1\leq x$.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if it decreased to $0$ because the proof just said linear and so I thought it could have higher slope in $[M-1,M]$ too. My interpretation is wrong.